# MFC: strange behavior of CDC and DrawText with DT_CALCRECT?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, mfc, gdi, visual-c++-6

In BeginPrinting, I calculate the printing rect like below. I rely on this to count the number of pages.

```
    CRect rect(30, -50, 200, -60);
    int height = pDC->DrawText(cstr, &rect, DT_EDITCONTROL | DT_WORDBREAK | DT_LEFT | DT_CALCRECT);
```

Then in OnPrint, I do the same calculation again. However, the height result is different. I don't know what could be wrong with it.

Comment: *in other cases, the bottom actually increases.* Could you please share the cstr you are trying to calculate? As I test with your sample, the bottom is always smaller than top, are you getting the height of the rect? Note that, `CRect::Height` Calculates the height of `CRect` by subtracting the top value from the bottom value. The resulting value can be negative. You can call `NormalizeRect` to normalize the rectangle before calling this function

Comment: Thank you for the help. My chase of this bug has turned into another route and I re-edit the question.

Comment: The DC for the screen and printer will have different characteristics, so naturally that will change the results you get.

Comment: I think OnPrint follows BeginPrinting, so naturally the same DC?

Comment: I use the cstr: `L"longlonglonglonglonglongword"`, and the `OnBeginPrinting` and `OnPrint` give me the same value: `{30 ,-50, 192, -84}` and rect.Height() = -34.